# Minimal stone piles

Tags: python

Question:
You are given a list of integer weights. You need to distribute these weights into two sets, such that the difference between the total weight of each set is as low as possible.
Input data: A list of the weights.
Output data: A number representing the lowest possible weight difference.

I saw an answer, but I cannot understand why bestval = -1. can anyone help me figure it out? thanks a lot!
code is following:

```
import itertools;

def checkio(stones):

    total = 0
    for cur in stones:
        total += cur

    bestval = -1

    for i in range(0,len(stones)):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(stones,i):
            weight = 0
            for item in comb:
                weight += item
            d = diff(total - weight, weight)
            if bestval == -1 or d < bestval:
                bestval = d                    
    return bestval

def diff(a,b):
    if a >= b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return b - a
```

Comment: howabout an initial value for a parameter to be used for the first iteration?

Comment: That is just what it is initialized to, inside of the most inner for loop it is overwritten if `d` is smaller than it.

Comment: ``bestval`` is set to ``-1`` so that, on the first pass through the for loop, ``bestval`` is set to ``d``. Thereafter, bestval will only be updated if a better d is found.

Comment: It's simply being used as a flag to let the program know if it has a best value yet or not.  `-1` was chosen as a value that is impossible to get otherwise (any other impossible value would also work).  It will be overwritten on the first iteration of that loop.

Comment: The loop that determines `total` could also determine the maximum value and then the code could use `bestval = maxval + 1` outside the main (triple) loop, avoiding testing `bestval == -1` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bestval` is just set to -1 initially and is updated the first time around the loop to `d`.  After that, `bestval` is updated again each time that `d` is a better value (aka smaller difference in weights) than the current `bestval`.

The key code is here...

```
if bestval == -1 or d < bestval:
    bestval = d
```

So on the first pass around the loop, `bestval == -1` is true, and `bestval` is updated.  After that, the `d < bestval` check determines whether to update the value.

Comment: Your explanation is clear and straight forward. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It is a starting value the you **know** can not be right so it gets replaced by the first answer no matter how bad!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that going through all the combinations is a brute force and slow method of solving the problem.

Sorting the weights by size and then, from heaviest to lightest, adding them one by one to the left or right pile depending on the weight difference between the piles will probably give the best answer.

Psuedo-code below, making it an O(n) problem (if sorting ignored);

```
sort weights into stack;
while (weight = pop stack) {
  if (sum(left) - sum(right) > 0) push weight on right
  else push weight to left;
}
bestval = sum(left) - sum(right);
```

e.g { 1, 2, 3, 4}

```
0. l 0 r 0 => 0 add 4 to left
1. l 4 r 0 => +4 add 3 to right
2. l 4 r 3 => +1 add 2 to right
3. l 4 r 5 => -1, add 1 to left
4. l 5 r 5 => same
```

Comment: Sorry, your method may not works sometimes. For example {1,2,3,4}.Still thanks a lot!

Comment: {1 2 3 4}
    0. l 0 r 0 => 0 add 4 to left
    1. l 4 r 0 => +4 add 3 to right
    2. l 4 r 3 => +1 add 2 to right
    3. l 4 r 5 => -1, add 1 to left
    4. l 5 r 5 => same

Comment: I know it was a long time ago, but demonstration my solution works added to answer

Answer (score 0):

The greedy algorithm suggested IS a good heuristic, but definitely NOT guaranteed to give a best solution.  This problem is NP-hard.  It can be "solved" stochastically using local search (simulated annealing, for example) - where solution means a "good" answer: one believed to be close to optimal.  Knuth proposed this problem, for 40 weights and three jars, with weights equal to the square roots of 1..40.

Gerry